# Save a temporary file to a MemoryStream and download it on an ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

So I'm following the documentation of google cloud storage. I have test class and method here that has a purpose to download the file from cloud storage.

Based from the documentation, you can find this:

```
public void DownloadFile(
        string bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name",
        string objectName = "my-file-name",
        string localPath = "my-local-path/my-file-name")
{
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    using var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(localPath);
    storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, outputFile);
}
```

In my scenario, I need something like this:

```
 public async Task<MemoryStream> DownloadFile(string file)
{
    string bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name",
    string localPath = "my-local-path/my-file-name"
    var storage = StorageClient.Create();
    using var memStream = new MemoryStream()
    await storage.DownloadObjectAsync(bucketName, file, memStream);
    return memStream;
}
```

And return the file from the ASP.NET Core Controller something like this:

```
[HttpGet("get-file-content/{id}"]
public async Task<FileContentResult> DownloadAsync(string id)
{
    var ms = await DownloadFile("some-name");
    var fileName = "something.txt";
    var mimeType="application/...."; 
    return new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), mimeType)
    {
        FileDownloadName = fileName
    };
}
```

Is it possible to achieve it? By the way, the 3rd argument of `storage.DownloadObject` is `Stream destination`

Comment: when you run the code, what errors do you see? What goes wrong? What have you observed?

Comment: That looks perfectly fine in principle. But you are disposing the memory stream in `DownloadFile`. If it is returned it should be disposed by the caller.

Comment: I get an error `Google.cloud.storage.v1.storagecliemtimp.<> ...`

Comment: then you should add it to your question.

Comment: @JonasH how can I achieve it or dispose it by the caller? It would be an additional knowledge for me

Comment: change `using var memStream = new MemoryStream()` to `var memStream = new MemoryStream()` You don't want to dispose of the stream.

Comment: Do I still need to dispose it in the Controller method?

Comment: Make sure you grant your access with download on the google cloud storage.

Comment: @Joker Bench move the 'using' from `using var memStream...` to `using var ms = await downloadFile`. However, memory streams do not use any non-memory resources, so disposing them are not super important.